# Get trending tags from instagram's api

Tags: python, api, instagram

Is there a way to get the top trending tags from instagram's api?
I currently don't see anything like this in the api docs, but curious as to what others have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-instagram1/index.html#retrievedetails/) might be helpful. Currently searching for something like this myself.

Update: [This](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/#) should be helpful